# How can I get children features of selected feature using CATIA macro for part simplification (Inactivate edgefillet, chamfer)?

Tags: vba, cad, catia

I m trying to inactivate the edge fillet and chamfer feature to simplify the CATIA model.
I made the macro code as follow.

However, obiously, if the other features refer the fillet or chamfer, the part cannot be updated.

Thus, I want to inactivate the all children features, but I cannot find how to get the children relationship of selected feature.

Please give me help or insight to solve this problem

Thank you for your help

```
Sub CATMain()

Dim partDocument1 As Document
Set partDocument1 = CATIA.ActiveDocument

Dim part1 As Part
Set part1 = partDocument1.Part

If Err.Number = 0 Then
    Dim selection1 As Selection
    Set selection1 = partDocument1.Selection
    
    selection1.Search "Name=*fillet*,all"
    
    If selection1.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No fillet features"
        
    Else
        For i = 1 To selection1.Count
            part1.Inactivate (selection1.Item2(i).Value)
        Next 'i
        'part1.Update
    End If
    
    Dim selection2 As Selection
    Set selection2 = partDocument1.Selection
    
    selection2.Search "Name=*chamfer*,all"
    
    If selection2.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No chamfer features"
        
    Else
        For j = 1 To selection2.Count
            part1.Inactivate (selection2.Item2(j).Value)
        Next 'j
        'part1.Update
    End If
    
    part1.Update
    
    MsgBox ( tot_f_c_num & " features are inactivated.")

Else
    MsgBox "Not a part document! Open a single part document."
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: afaik there is no method to get the children of a feature by a macro. You could try to loop  trough: update, check if part is updated, if not search for the feature which fails, deactivate this feature, restart loop

Comment: You are now discovering that my comment in your other question is true: Manipulating feature activity is a dark hole of doom. 

If you have KWA then there are ways to do what you want. But not by manipulating activity parameters.

Comment: @Shrotter I cant also find any related reference. I will try again considering your comments. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @CRJohnson Now I truly know. But we dont have KWA license thus I tried to manipulating feature activity for model simplification in CATIA. Thank you for your reply

Answer (score 0):

@Shrotter I modified my macro as follow; it seems to work well at this time, but may have problem ::

```
Sub CATMain()
Dim partDocument1 As Document
Set partDocument1 = CATIA.ActiveDocument
Dim part1 As Part
Set part1 = partDocument1.Part
If Err.Number = 0 Then
    Dim selection1 As Selection
    Set selection1 = partDocument1.Selection
    selection1.Search "Name=*fillet*,all"
    If selection1.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No fillet features"
    Else
        For i = 1 To selection1.Count
            part1.Inactivate (selection1.Item2(i).Value)
        Next 'i
    End If
    Dim selection2 As Selection
    Set selection2 = partDocument1.Selection
    selection2.Search "Name=*chamfer*,all"
    If selection2.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No chamfer features"
    Else
        For j = 1 To selection2.Count
            part1.Inactivate (selection2.Item2(j).Value)
        Next 'j
    End If
    Dim selection3 As Selection
    Set selection3 = partDocument1.Selection
    selection3.Search "Name=*,all"
    For k = 1 To selection3.Count
        On Error Resume Next
        part1.UpdateObject (selection3.Item2(k).Value)
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            part1.Inactivate (selection3.Item2(k).Value) 
        End If
    Next 'k
Else
    MsgBox "Not a part document! Open a single part document."
End If
End Sub
```